# How to pass 3 query parameter in talend tRESTClient

Tags: talend, rest-client

I'm using Talend Big Data for pulling data from HP ALM to mongoDB using tRESTClient. Already i am passing two query parameters(**query,page-size**) in tRESTClient. Now i have tried with one more parameter **last-modified** like this **query1={last-modified[>=(2017-06-21)]}**. But it is not taking as a parameter.
Below i've mentioned tRESTClient component detail.
[image]

How can i pass 3rd parameter with the tRESTClient?

Answer (score 1):

Just bellow the Query parameters box, you can find easily a green `+` button that adds new line for a new paramerter

[image]

Comment: I have tried with the name of "query1" as a 3rd parameter, but that is not working & also mentioned above.